# How to get power of x which is smaller or equal than a given number n?

Tags: algorithm, c++11, math

I have problem where there are two numbers given x and n , the task is to find a power of x which is just equal or smaller than n . I know i can do this by starting a loop but it seems not so efficient solution, i want to know any solution which is in o(1) or something efficient.

Comment: Do you want the largest such power? This is just x ^ floor(log_base_x (n) ), assuming x > 1

Comment: Yess. Thank Youu

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `log` with `floor`. There can be a few surprising rounding errors. The loop solution only takes log n / log x iterations, which is not a lot if n is at most a 64-bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something along this line :

```
int foo (int x, int n) {  
    int counter = x;
    int pow = 1;
    while(counter < n) {
        pow =+ pow
        counter =* counter ;
    }
    if(counter == n)
        return pow;
    while(x > n) {
        counter = counter/x;
        pow--;
    }
    return pow;
}
```

I think overall in the worst case scenario its still O(log(n)) but in certain cases it should perform better.